# Traefik ingress 404s

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, kubernetes-ingress

I am running a traefik ingress controller on GKE (1.8.5-gke.0) deployed with Helm. What I'm observing is that the requests are frequently getting a 404 response.

What it looks like is traefik is reloading it's configs constantly even when nothing is changing in it's config or the ingresses which are defined.

The versions of traefik I've used for this are 1.3.8 and 1.5.2, both are doing the same thing.

Comment: Could you please start Traefik with DEBUG level logs enabled (i.e., `--logLevel=DEBUG`) and paste the output?

Answer (score 2):

The flipping behavior was being caused by the same ingress being loaded into two different namespaces, not sure if that's because of the conflicting endpoints or the naming.

One namespace didn't have the service defined which is why it was 404 on one and 200 OK on the other.

Comment: You might want to consider accepting your own answer as the correct one, since it may help people in a similar situation.